# Is it possible to make a x-www-form-urlencoded POST request through InvokeHttp

Tags: apache-nifi

I just started using Nifi and i would like to know if it's possible to perform a POST with a content-type set to `x-www-form-urlencoded`. I need to pass these key/values to my request :

```
grant_type: refresh_token
client_id:  myClientId
client_secret:  myClientSecret
refresh_token:  myRefreshToken
```

I try to made somethink with the FlowFile Form Data Name property
[image]

But the request sended looks like this : [image]

I would like the key/value like this (sended as `Content-type : application/x-www-urlencoded`) : [image]

Answer (score 3):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html

> When the HTTP Method is POST, dynamic properties with the property name in the form of `post:form:<NAME>`, where the  will be the form data name, will be used to fill out the `multipart form parts`.

so, `post:form:<NAME>` could be used for `multipart/form-data`

and you want `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

format of http body should be `parm1=Value1&parm2=Value2`

before calling invokeHttp use replaceText with approximately this expression in `replacement value`:

```js
client_secret=${client_secret:urlEncode()}&client_secret=${client_secret:urlEncode()}&...
```

then use invokehttp with

```
Send Message Body = true
Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```